# NGINX pointing different docker compose containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am new to docker and I ran into an architectural problem:
I have two sets of container (CUSTOMER1, CUSTOMER2) running in my computer by the same docker-compose file which, both, contains two same applications (APP1, APP2).

My question is: Is there a way, using an nginx server **in the same host**, to **access** to the **desired app in the desired container** (ex: APP1 into CUSTOMER1 container by browser link (ex: CUSTOMER1.MYPC.IT/APP1) **through my computer** using **Windows containers**?

Here I attach a graphical representation for better explaination:

[image showing an host called "my_computer" which is running two different container, both with two applications running (APP1, APP2) with an external nginx server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujUwr.png)

Here, is the nginx.conf file from the nginx container:

```
worker_processes  auto;
events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  99999;

     server {
            listen 80;
            server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;
            resolver 127.0.0.11;
            location /APP1 {
                proxy_pass          http://test_app1/......;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr; 
                proxy_read_timeout 300;
                proxy_connect_timeout 300;
                proxy_send_timeout 300;
            }

            location /APP2 {
                include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
                proxy_pass          http://test_app2/......;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here, is my Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
    app1basecontainer:
        image: app1baseimg
        build: ./APP1BASEIMG
        volumes:
            - apps1hared:C:\DEFAULT\APPPortal
        expose:
            - 8080
    app2basecontainer:
        depends_on: 
            - "appbasecontainer"
        image: app2baseimg
        build: ./APP2BASEIMG
        volumes:
            - apps2hared:C:\DEFAULT\APPPortal
        expose:
            - 80


volumes:
    apps1hared:
    apps2shared:
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Can you show your docker compose files?

Comment: Did you try the [automated nginx-proxy for docker](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy)? It is extremely easy to use and does what you want with just a few lines in you `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: @DannyB unfortunately, it seem that docker-gen it doesn't work with windows

Comment: Do you have 2 compose file you mean ?

Comment: @Amin No, I have a single compose file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2 Options:**

**1-** Bind container ports to outside, then proxy to them:

```yaml
services:
    app1basecontainer:
        ...
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
    app2basecontainer:
        ...
        ports:
            - 80:80
```

Then, in your Nginx conf:

```
server{
    location /APP1 {
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
    }
    location /APP2 {
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:80;
    }
}
```

**2-** Nginx container to your docker-compose, then apps and nginx are in the same network, and nginx can see apps containers. Then your nginx conf changes to :

```
server{
    location /APP1 {
        proxy_pass          http://CONTAINER_NAME:8080;
    }
    location /APP2 {
        proxy_pass          http://CONTAINER_NAME:80;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I have a single compose file. With that single compose file, I can run both sets of compose-container (customer1 and customer2 container in the image)